# 3 O(n) operations consecutively nested, but still a total Big O of O(n^2). Why?

Tags: python, big-o

> Question : "evaluate the average and the worst-case complexity, using the following notation : n = len(a)."

```
def anagramme_list(a, b):
    # Time complexity : O(n^2) O(n^2)
    # Space complexity : ~O(n) (list made out of a string)

    res = False  # O(1) O(1)

    if len(a) == len(b):  # (cond O(1)) O(n^2) O(n^2)
        liste_b = list(b)  # O(n) O(n)
        res = True  # O(1) O(1)

        for i in a:  # (it: O(n)) O(n^2) O(n^2)
            if i in liste_b:  # (cond O(n)) O(n) O(n)
                liste_b.remove(i)  # O(n) O(n)
            else:  # O(1) O(1)
                res = False  # O(1) O(1)

    return res
```

I would've said that, in the worst case scenario, we got O(n^3) since there's an operation in O(n) (liste_b.remove(i)) triggered by a condition in O(n) (if i in liste_b) which is itself nested in a loop in O(n). No need to say that this answer surprised me...
Could anyone please explain why is the nested operation in O(n) not considered to be "nested" in its parent (the 'if i in liste_b'), and, on a broader level, how to approach the big O evaluation in this type of case please ?

Comment: It wasn't your original question, but there is no way of knowing the "average" running time of this program without some a priori knowledge of about what `a` and `b` look like.  Given the universe of all possible lists, the odds that two picked at random have the same length is nearly zero.  So your program will run in O(1) in almost all cases.

Comment: @FrankYellin yeah, sorry for not having stated that we only took in consideration the cases in which len(a) == len(b). Thanks for the precision !

Answer (score 1):

It is O(²). O(³) is not a tight bound for it. Let's reduce this problem by removing the `for i in a` loop wrapper. Then we just have the `if..else` block. Note that there is no loop nesting here anymore, because `liste_b.remove(i)` is not executed *for every* internal step that is needed to execute `i in liste_b`; on the contrary, first `i in list_b` is executed to completion, and only then (possibly) `liste_b.remove(i)` is executed *once*. So this `if` block does not represent θ(²) actions in the worst case, but θ(+) actions, which is still O().